# How does the SSH server know the length of data encrypted?

Tags: ssh

In am learning the SSH [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1)

> An encryption algorithm and a key will be negotiated during the key
> exchange.  When encryption is in effect, **the packet length**, padding
> length, payload, and padding fields of each packet MUST be encrypted
> with the given algorithm.

So the structure of the packet would be like that. How does the SSH server or client know the real length of the encrypted data?

```
                                  payload
                 [byte[packet_length - padding_length - 1]]
                                     ^
                                     |
       packet_length                 |             mac (Message Authentication Code - MAC)
          [uint32]                   |                        [byte[mac_length]]
             ^                       |                                ^
             |                       |                                |
             |                       |                                |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |    |                       |   ssh                          |      |
|       | +----------------------------------------------------------------+ |
|       | |-----------------------------------------------------|     |    | |
|       | || |  |   |                |               |         ||     |    | |
|  tcp  | || |  |   |                |               |         ||     |    | |
|       | || +  | + |            +   +               |    +    ||     +    | |
|       | ||    | | |            |                   |    |    ||          | |
|       | |-----------------------------------------------------|          | |
|       | |----------------------------------------------------------------+ |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
                  |              |                        |
                  |              |                        |
                  |              |                        |
                  v              |                        v
               [byte]            |              [byte[padding_length]]
            padding_length       |                  random padding
                                 |
                                 |
                                 |
                                 |
                                 |
                                 |
                                 |
                                 v
                           encrypted_data
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Cryptography. This is basic TCP/IP problem.

Comment: Possibly but this is a question about a cryptographic protocol, and hence I'm allowing this question. TCP is a streaming protocol, so I don't see how that transmits the message size other than closing the connection, and I'd be surprised if that's used.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the SSH protocol:

> "Note that the 'packet_length' field is also encrypted, and processing it requires special care when sending or receiving packets."

Generally ciphers process bytes from left to right. This means that the packet length can be available before the encryption is ended (or before all the information is received, for that matter).

This is a horrible protocol decision because it means you have to interleave between the packet decoding and decryption layer, and you will get the message length before it is authenticated. Still, it is practically doable.

There is probably one advantage: you can add more padding to avoid some side channel attacks that use the length of the send packages. However, this advantage is hard to use, because you'd now also have to mix the application and encryption code.

Note that the other sizes - such as MAC length - are determined by the protocol and protocol configuration during the handshake.

Comment: However I read almost whole RFC and there is no specific packet length configuration but an agreement about the max length and min length.As far as I knew TCP is a streaming protocol, so how does the SSH process to detect the packet boundary once the receiver process didn't receive the data from system buffer and  2 time's data stick together.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem solution is in TCP header. With reference to TCP header, there is a field called 'HLen' which means header-length. By stripping off this header the whole remaining bits are the SSH package (i mean header and data). SSH can decrypt this whole package of bits and then starts reading the decrypted packet according to SSH semantics.
SSH semantics says: first 4 bytes are the Packet-length. The 5th byte is the padding length ... So on

Comment: In the end TCP turns a data stream in to a series of messages / segments. However, that kind of functionality is commonly hidden to the user (it is a layered architecture after all, even though TCP/IP is not strictly OSI). If you're correct then you'd need access to information present on a lower level.

Comment: No layer in TCP/IP or OSI models have access to the information of another layer. After all, segmentation/reassembly is a L4 problem. In this case, SSH must control buffer size before sending data to the TCP socket. buffer must be small enough to guarantee MAC correctness and cipher padding correctness. Also, note that most terminal systems work in character mode, which means send one byte as the user type it in.